# How come my duplicate also affects the original?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add copies to an array with some modification:

```
  site.pages.dup.each do | page |
    new_page = page.dup
    data = new_page.data
    data['permalink'] = File.join('/app', page.url)
    data['layout'] = 'app'
    site.pages << new_page
  end

  site.pages.each do | page |
    puts page.data
  end
```

When I output page.data, the permalinks are different, but `data['layout']` is the same for all items in the array. I also tried data = `new_page.data.dup` and writing out `new_page.data` in each instance.

Comment: `dup` is shallow, just like the docs say. `data` is local; you need to dupe the data *into* the new object.

Comment: how do i do that, tried `new_page.data = page.data.clone` and `new_page.data = page.data.dup`

Comment: also, how come it affects .layout, but not .permalink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Moved comment to answer for formatting.)

Please provide an example of the data; I have zero issues working with a similar structure, e.g.,

```
pages = [
  {
    'name' => 'page 1',
    'data' => {
      'permalink' => 'p1 perma',
      'layout'    => 'p1 layout'
    }
  },

  {
    'name' => 'page 2',
    'data' => {
      'permalink' => 'p2 perma',
      'layout'    => 'p2 layout'
    }
  },
]
```

If I use (essentially) your code, plus my comment:

```
pages.dup.each do |p|
  new_page = p.dup

  new_data = new_page['data'].dup

  new_data['layout']    = 'app'
  new_data['permalink'] = "#{new_data['permalink']} whatever"

  new_page['data'] = new_data

  pages << new_page
end
```

I get the following output:

```
[{"name"=>"page 1", "data"=>{"permalink"=>"p1 perma", "layout"=>"p1 layout"}},
 {"name"=>"page 2", "data"=>{"permalink"=>"p2 perma", "layout"=>"p2 layout"}},
 {"name"=>"page 1", "data"=>{"permalink"=>"p1 perma whatever", "layout"=>"app"}},
 {"name"=>"page 2", "data"=>{"permalink"=>"p2 perma whatever", "layout"=>"app"}}]
```

Unrelated, but I'd separate the array concatenation; instead, consider `map`ping over pages and creating a new array with the original `pages` and the modified ones. Right now you're doing an extra `dup` that shouldn't be necessary, and it adds some confusion.

I'd also break out the `data` dup/modification into a separate method (and possibly the entire dupe process altogether) to really keep things tight, roughly:

```
def modify_page_data(data)
  new_data = data.dup

  new_data['permalink'] = "#{data['permalink']} whatever"
  new_data['layout'] = 'app'

  new_data
end

def dup_page(page)
  new_page = page.dup
  new_page['data'] = modify_page_data(page['data'])
  new_page
end

new_pages = pages.map(&method(:dup_page))
```

Then you can `concat` or whatever you want with the original `pages` and the modified new pages.

https://github.com/davelnewton/stackoverflow/tree/master/ruby/51289405

Comment: This is a great answer but `new_data = new_page['data'].dup` outputs `jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  can't dup NilClass`

Comment: I got it working with new_data = new_page['data'].dup

 but then `new_page['data'] = new_data` outputs `jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  undefined method []=' for #<Jekyll::Page @name="about_us.md"> Did you mean?  []`

Comment: new_page['data'] is empty but new_page.data is a hash.

Comment: @Himmators That's why you need to be specific; as I said, I made up a data structure because there was no way to know what you were actually dealing with. You'll need to modify the example to fit the data structure(s)/instance(s)/etc. you're actually dealing with. The idea will be the same.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to ruby so it's kind of hard to figure out where the errors are comming from.

Comment: @Himmators That one is pretty easy; you can't set data back into a Jekyll `Page` instance this way. I suspect there are a few problems going on at once here--you might want to take a short step back and figure out enough Ruby to know what's going on, and try to break the problem down into smaller chunks and tackle them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that dup is only a shallow copy. What this means that it creates a duplicate of the first layer, the array itself, but not any of the deeper layers.

You might want to consider a gem like full_dup that adds the full_dup method that digs down as deep as needed to create a full duplicate of the data.

Full disclosure: I wrote the full_dup gem. There may be other gems that would work just as well.

Comment: Is there a way to copy only that node, i tried  tried new_page.data = page.data.clone and new_page.data = page.data.dup

Comment: also, how come it affects .layout, but not .permalink?

Comment: Your attempt to dup the deeper data structure fails because there is yet another layer below that one. The page.data is itself a hash, so dup only duplicates the topmost hash level. The contents of the hash remained shared references.